# New to unity and particles & gravity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to Unity3D and thought I'd give it a go to make physics models.

Here is what I would like to do:

Particles, white small ones, that "stream" outwards from a point, 360 degrees(4/3*πr3) in a shape of a sphere, a growing sphere. The paritcle system should release new bursts of "expanding spheres" quite rapidly and sometimes not as rapid. If I add another primitive to the scene, the particles should bounce in the opposite direction when they hit the surface of that primitive and when they bounce the particle "loses energy" and starts to fade away eventually.

I found the "Particle System" but it does not seem to spawn a ready flow of particles to generate a "exploding effect" that I am after. I hope someone with more experience could help me out :)

Comment: Particle System's Emission can add a burst, maybe you can use it to make an "exploding effect".

Comment: Yes, it can. The problem is however to get the particles to bounce of on other object in the scene. Ultimatly what I want to accomplish is to simulate some wave mechanics.

Comment: Isn't there a setting somewhere to make particles collide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the options under the particle system called bounce. and set it from 0 to 1 depending on how much you wanted it to bounce off. everything inside of the collisions tab is what you want, and adding a set amount of burst, would give the impression of a wave, bursts are under emission they need an amount and delay from start of the system.
For the sphere shape you go under the shape category and change shape from cone to sphere.
hope this helps.